# Overuse of factory pattern

Tags: design-patterns, factory

Where should I not use factory pattern because everyone around me tells me not to instantiate concrete object.Factories are not easy to deal with when it comes to testing and I do not want to create factory for every possible object that I create.
On the top of all this confusion,why do I need to have singleton factory?

Comment: Maybe i'm just being nitpicky...but somewhere, sometime, somehow, you *do* have to instantiate a concrete object.  If you don't, you won't have any objects to work with.  The question is where, when, and how you do it.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need a singleton.  Period.  You wanna talk about testability...that'll all but kill it right there.

Comment: yeah i know the same but I don't know why people use it?What's the purpose of using it

Comment: Singleton?  It's easy to grok, and it gives global-happy people a feeling like they're designing stuff properly cause *hey, it's in the GoF book!*.  (Big mistake, IMO.)  Also, they probably don't have a clue about dependency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should program against interfaces, using factory patterns for everything is madness.

A singleton can be useful but again only if needed / wanted.

The main thing is not to use things you dont understand or dont see the point of, worth a read of Martin Fowlers book then think about it again and you might conclude a middle path is right for you.

In programming there is no right/wrong depends on many factors.  Even using an interface for everything can be a pain but it has always paid of for me.

Answer (score 1):

An interface type is a specification of a protocol, potentially supported by many object types. Use [base classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybz98h0.aspx) instead of interfaces whenever possible. From a versioning perspective, classes are more flexible than interfaces. With a class, you can ship Version 1.0 and then in Version 2.0 add a new method to the class. As long as the method is not abstract, any existing derived classes continue to function unchanged.

For example, providing an interface for data adapters is difficult and serves no real benefit. Developers will still have to program against each adapter specifically, so there is only marginal benefit from providing an interface. However, you do need to support consistency between all adapters. Although an interface or abstract class is not appropriate in this situation, providing a consistent pattern is very important. You can provide consistent patterns for developers in base classes. Follow these guidelines for creating base classes.

Interfaces are appropriate in the following situations:

- Several unrelated classes want to support the protocol.
- These classes already have established base classes (for example, some are user interface (UI) controls, and some are XML Web services).
- Aggregation is not appropriate or practical.

In all other situations, class inheritance is a better model.